# Connecting signal to slot immediately causes signal to be emitted

Tags: python, pyqt, python-3.3, pyqt5

I am writing a program with python 3.3.3 and pyqt5.  I have connected many signals and slots with no problem.  This one is causing a problem.  My code follows:

```
   def populateVendorAndModelComboBoxes(self, vendorComboBox, modelComboBox):
    dictVendors = {}
    #for rclass in sorted(list(directory.DRV_TO_RADIO.values())):
    for rclass in list(directory.DRV_TO_RADIO.values()):
        if not issubclass(rclass, chirp_common.CloneModeRadio) and \
                not issubclass(rclass, chirp_common.LiveRadio):
            continue

        if not rclass.VENDOR in dictVendors:
            dictVendors[rclass.VENDOR] = []

        dictVendors[rclass.VENDOR].append(rclass)

    vendorComboBox.addItems(sorted(list(dictVendors)))

    def _vendorChanged(vendorCBox, vendorsDict, modelCBox):

        modelsList = vendorsDict[vendorCBox.currentText()]

        added_models = []

        modelCBox.clear()
        for rclass in modelsList:
            if rclass.MODEL not in added_models:
                added_models.append(rclass.MODEL)
        print("adding to modelCB")
        modelCBox.addItems(sorted(added_models))
        print("Done adding to modelCB")

    vendorComboBox.currentTextChanged.connect(_vendorChanged(vendorComboBox, dictVendors, modelComboBox))
    _vendorChanged(vendorComboBox, dictVendors, modelComboBox)
```

This code populates comboboxes with vendors and models.  The vendor combobox is populated at startup.  The model combobox is filled with different data for each vendor.  Every time the user picks a different vendor, the model combobox must be updated with a different list.

What should happen:

When the method populateVendorAndModelComboBoxes is called, the first part of the program puts the vendor list in the vendor combobox.  Then a connection will be made between the currentTextChanged signal and the _vendorChanged slot.  Then the _vendorChanged function should be initially called to setup the Model combobox.  From then on, the _vendorChanged function should be called whenever the user picks a new vendor.

What is happening:

When the connection is made between the currentTextChanged signal and the _vendorChanged slot, the _vendorChanged function is immediately called.  It should not immediately call the _vendorChanged function.  This does not happen with any of my other signal / slot connections.  The _vendorChanged function is executed with out error, then the execution point drops back to the vendorComboBox.currentTextChanged.connect.... statement and I immediately get an error TypeError: argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'.

If I comment out the statement that makes the connection, the program works without error.  The vendor combobox is filled with vendors and the model combobox is filled with models of the first vendor in the list.  That indicates that the _vendorChanges code is working properly.

I have two questions.  Why does the connect statement cause the _vendorChanged function to be immediately executed?  What is the cause of the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on ekhumoro's answer, you could also let the signal pass the currentText to the lambda function.  This means you would just pass the text into the function and not have to get the currentText later.

```
def _vendorChanged(vendorText, vendorsDict, modelCBox):

    modelsList = vendorsDict[vendorText]

    added_models = []

    modelCBox.clear()
    for rclass in modelsList:
        if rclass.MODEL not in added_models:
            added_models.append(rclass.MODEL)
    print("adding to modelCB")
    modelCBox.addItems(sorted(added_models))
    print("Done adding to modelCB")

vendorComboBox.currentTextChanged[str].connect(
    lambda vendorText: _vendorChanged(vendorText, dictVendors, modelComboBox))
```

Also, if you don't need the references to dictVendors and modelComboBox to update based on the current scope of the lambda function every time the signal is emitted, you could leave them out of the parameter list and let the _vendorChanged function simply inherit them from it's parent scope (which is the same as the lambda's parent scope... so I'm not sure there's be any difference...). The appeal of this is that you no longer need the lamda to provide the signal with a callable... you can give it the _vendorChanged function directly:

```
def _vendorChanged(vendorText):

    modelsList = dictVendors[vendorText]

    added_models = []

    modelComboBox.clear()
    for rclass in modelsList:
        if rclass.MODEL not in added_models:
            added_models.append(rclass.MODEL)
    print("adding to modelCB")
    modelComboBox.addItems(sorted(added_models))
    print("Done adding to modelCB")

vendorComboBox.currentTextChanged[str].connect(_vendorChanged)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Your answer and @ekhumoro are very helpful.  Yours simplifies the function.  I am still stuck on one thing.  Why did eliminating vendorsDict and modelCBox allow me to eliminate the lambda?  Or why did putting them in force me to need to use lambda?  Can I mark both your replies as answers?

Comment: It has to do with the fact that functions are objects in python. Say you define a function with `def myFunc(arg): return arg*2` or the same thing as a lambda: `myFunc = lambda arg: arg*2` ... when you type just `myFunc` at the Python interpreter it will return <function __main__.MyFunc> or <function __main__.lambda>. This function object hasn't been called, it's just the definition of a function which can be stored, passed around, renamed, etc. When you call it by putting parentheses after it and possibly passing parameters to it, the result is whatever is returned.

Comment: The return value is often not a function, but a bool, int, string, list, or None if there is no return statement.  In fact if you primarily write functions that return other functions, you're implementing Functional Programming. Anyway, Signals must be connected to Slots and a Slot must be callable, basically it must be an uncalled function.  That way whenever the signal is emitted, the slot is then called... so for checkbox.clicked.connect(slot), when the box is clicked, slot is called like slot(). If it was checkbox.clicked[bool].connect(slot) then it'd be called as slot(True) if checked.

Comment: The lambda is used to generate a quick callable function on the fly, with the advantage that you can pass arguments to another function.  This is useful for Signals and Slots because it allows you to use functions as Slots which take more arguments than the signal emits. Without the lambda, your slot function must take 1 or 0 arguments (depending on whether you connect to a signal which carries data).  With the lambda, the lambda is like a proxy, provided the interface that the signal needs (0 or 1 inputs) while feeding your function additional arguments.

Comment: Also the function inside the lambda doesn't get called until the lambda get's called, just like the contents of a function definition aren't executed until the function is called... Any of this making sense?

Comment: Yes.  It does make sense.  Here is what I understand.  If a slot function has 0 or 1 arguments, it will be callable without lambda.  If a slot requires more than 1 argument, it will be called and the signal will be sent to what is returned by the function, not to the function itself.  To fix this, use lambda.  To connect to a function with 0 arguments use something like checkbox.clicked.connect(slot).

Comment: To connect to a function with 1 argument use combobox.currentTextChanged[str].connect(slot) and the signal will pass the string to the slot.  If the function has >1 arguments, use lambda.  Correct?

Comment: Sounds like you've got it!  I made a quick signal-slot mockup without Qt to demonstrate how saving a function object and calling it later works... http://pastebin.com/6SwHXC3S

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by attempting to connect to the *result* of a function call (which in this case is `None`), instead of the function object itself. Of course, this also explains why the function is executed immedaitely.

You should wrap the function call in a `lambda`, like this:

```
    vendorComboBox.currentTextChanged.connect(
        lambda: _vendorChanged(vendorComboBox, dictVendors, modelComboBox))
```

Comment: Adding lambda fixed my problem but I don't understand why.  Why did my statement attempt to connect to the result of the function call instead of the function itself?  Does it have something to do with closure?  Or with something in the way I wrote _vendorChanged?  None of my other connect statements act this way.  I notice when I put a breakpoint on this connect statement, my debugger says _vendorChanged is a function, whereas with the other connect statements the debugger says I am connecting to a "bound method".  I can't figure out why the others worked without lambda but this one doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent answers but just want to add this explanation:

Doing

```
vendorComboBox.currentTextChanged.connect(_vendorChanged(vendorComboBox, dictVendors, modelComboBox))
```

is the same as doing

```
obj = _vendorChanged(vendorComboBox, dictVendors, modelComboBox)
vendorComboBox.currentTextChanged.connect(obj)
```

Now you should see that `obj` is not a function but the result of calling your `_vendorChanged` function with the 3 parameters. This means that you get the *impression* that the signal is immediately fired, thereby calling your function, but in fact it's just your function executing as directed. The second problem is that `_vendorChanged` does not return anything so obj is in fact None. Since you are trying to connect a signal to None, you get this error. The solution is given in other answers.